# Restoring from IPSW. Unable to connect to gs.apple.com (error 3014)

Tags: itunes, ipad, jailbreak, software-update

I had been running jailbroken ios7 on my iPad for a long time. Last month I  decided to update to 8.4
Downloading the update from itunes failed a few times so I grabbed the file from apple servers myself

When I tried to restore using the ipsw file, itunes gave me `3014` error. I tried again next day, same error. 
I'm running windows 10 x64 and I have:

- Made sure my HOSTS file is not causing it. There is
  definitely nothing apple related in there.
- Checked my firewall rules, disabled the firewall. That did not help either
- performed restore process multiple times with no luck
- Tried pinging `gs.apple.com` from another computer with windows 7.. it times out just the same

Its been more than a month now and my iPad is just sitting there...

Itunes network dianosis shows me this -

```
Firewall Information

Windows Firewall is off.

Connection attempt to Apple web site was successful.
Connection attempt to browsing iTunes Store was successful.
Connection attempt to purchasing from iTunes Store was successful.
Connection attempt to iPhone activation server was successful.
Connection attempt to firmware update server was unsuccessful.
The network connection timed out.
Connection attempt to Gracenote server was successful.
Last successful iTunes Store access was 2015-08-16 13:05:38.
```

### ---------------

The server I cannot connect to is `gs.apple.com`. I believe that's what causing itunes to throw the error (3014)

Tried pinging it, failed - 
[image]

Suprisingly, however, I can access it from the browser (why/how?) 
[image]

My iPhone can recieve updates just fine over the same network. I'm stumped, can someone help me out, am i missing something?

If there's a way to update without the itunes server-check I'd love to hear it. Methods involving jailbreak are welcome

Comment: Check this below troubleshooting guide; https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204770#error3014

Comment: Like I stated in my question, I've tried the methods written in Official apple support docs

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP (over IP) which is a completely separate protocol from TCP (over IP), used by http, which is why there's nothing unusual about the fact that you cannot ping `gs.apple.com` but can access  over it http using a browser. I'm afraid I cannot help with the Jailbreaking issues, but I think your inability to ping isn't the cause. I can't ping `gs.apple.com` either.

Comment: Friend had this problem too. Tried from another pc and worked

Comment: Also make sure that you have latest version of iTunes

Comment: Hope it helps you

Comment: Where is the GS error logged? Can you upload the file to github gist and link here if it's too long to embed? What version of iTunes? What Windows version?

Answer (score 2):

Enter DFU Mode, and **then** try a restore. Method:

First, plug the iPad into your computer, and then power it off. Make sure iTunes is running on your PC.

Now *press and hold* both the Power button and Home button simultaneously, until you see the Apple logo. Now let go of the Power button while still holding down the Home button. iTunes can now associate with the device and is told that the iPad is in Recovery Mode.

Finally, simply Restore your iPad to the ipsw file that you downloaded (or just restore, whatever your choice is).

**Just in case** you didn't know, in order to restore an iOS device to a certain backup/ipsw file located on your *Windows computer*, shift-click the **Restore iPad** ( / iPhone / iPod) button in iTunes and find & pick the file manually.

(Note: There is a tool I know of called [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com). There's actually a desktop version of it as well. Unfortunately, however, it apparently only works with iOS 8.3 and 8.4 in the jailbreak version of the tool.)

Answer (score 0):

Fix Date/Time & update iTunes:

First method is easiest of all three. You have to check for date and time on your computer whether it is correct or not? Many people were getting this error because date and time on their computer was incorrect and they got this error fixed after correcting the date and time. It is also advisable to update iTunes to latest version of iTunes. You can check for updates by by opening iTunes and then clicking on “check for updates”. If any updates are available iTunes will inform you about those updates and you can install those updates.

Turn off Antivirus:

Sometimes the antivirus program installed on your computer may conflict with the host file of your computer which results in iTunes error 3014. So if you turn off your antivirus for sometime and then try to restore through iTunes you won’t get error 3014.

Fix Host File:

This is the most effective method of all three. In this method you are basically fixing the host file of your computer. Follow these steps to fix the host file on your computer.

1. To access the host file on your computer you have to go to

   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2. Delete the HOSTS file found in this directory. (you will need administrator access for deleting the hosts file.)
3. Download Hosts file from the bottom of this post and copy the downloaded hosts file in the same directory. (you will need administrator access for copying the hosts file.)
4. Once host file is copied in the above directory restart your computer and start restoring your device through iTunes.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your host file that is causing problem connecting with gs.apple.com.

This post will help you fix your host file.

http://www.yourtechinfo.com/2015/08/top-3-ways-to-fix-itunes-error-3014.html

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

go to C:Windows/System32/Drivers/Etc

and open the hosts file in notepad

and at the botton of the text file add this:

74.208.105.171 gs.apple.com

(Numer Symbol)74.208.10.249 GS.APPLE.COM

(Numer Symbol)127.0.0.1 GS.APPLE.COM

(Numer Symbol)74.208.105.171 GS.APPLE.COM

then Save! (You may save it on the desktop and then replace it with the old one)